# Multicore, shards, merging indexes, SolrCloud: Which to use?

Tags: solr

I'm hoping that someone can tell me what is the best way to handle the following scenario:

I have three types of entities (e1, e2, e3) in a database, each in their own table. These entities have their own primary key (e1.[k1], e2.[k2], e3.[k3]) and some common fields and some unique ones.

```
e1.[k1], e1.k2?, e1.k3?, e1.commonfield, e1.uniquefield
e2.[k2], e2.k3?, e2.commonfield
e3.[k3], e3.commonfield
```

Where: [primary key], optional?

Currently, I'm using four cores, three of them map onto these entities, and have their own import/deltaImport that uses the primary key of that specific entity to do the import. The fourth core uses the other three as shards, so that all three entity types can be searched at the same time. This requires the schema for all four cores to be identical.

```
[id], k1?, k2?, k3?, commonfield, uniquefield?
```

The Solr document id is generated using CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory / ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory by concatenating the primary key values.

I'm doubtful if this is the correct way to go about it. Technically, this is not a candidate for sharding, but I'm unsure what other approach I could or should follow. For this particular example, is this a good approach? Are there better options?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big are the contents and count for these three entities? and how many columns ?
Cause if the content is less the index size would still be manageable in a Single core.
You can still hold the all data in a single Core.

Also you can design your primary to be unique based on the entities and have other fields as normal fields.

Fields :- `id, k1, k2, k3, commonfield, uniquefield, entity_type`

Unique key id field for Solr which will be assigned valued as per entities, so that the uniqueness is maintained. 
e.g.
Primary key for e1 -> e1+k1
Primary key for e2 -> e2+k2
Primary key for e3 -> e3+k3

And maintain the other fields as is.
You can also add entity_type field which will have value e1, e2, e3 to be able to filter if needed on each entity.
This approach would also work for sharding.

Comment: Hi Jayendra, thank you for responding so quickly. I'm afraid I don't fully understand your reply. Are you saying that in one Core, I can have different entities with different keys? The sentence "Cause in the content.." I can't parse that sentence so I don't know what it means. The number of columns is about 25, the number of records is about 5 million.

Comment: In one core you can host different entities and you can define a unqie key as mentioned in the answer. Just append the entity name with the primary key so that you have a surrogate type primary key and you can maintain different fields for rest.

Comment: Corrected the Answer .. Cause *if* the content.. Also club the index and check what the size is and is it manageable in a single index.

Comment: I have worked with generating a unique document id before, but this does not work in the delta import, because at that time, the id is not generated yet. Right now, I have adapted my SQL View to add an extra column with an id generated by concatenating k1, k2 and k3, but I find this not very elegant. Would you say that the approach described here and suggested by you has weighty advantages over the multicore approach?

Comment: If you index size is less and managable in a Single core this would be the best approach.  Id generation is auto generated but would depend on the fields within so deltas would work as well. And keep the fields all seperated would give you more control.

Comment: Perhaps I've done something wrong, but I had an auto generated id before, as mentioned in the question, but the delta import did *not* work.

Comment: For delta imports the Id must be the same as solr would update the document based on the id. If you have auto generated one its not possible to know the Id to overwrite

Comment: Yes, I know that... So how can I generate that same id during the delta import?

Comment: so instead of auto generating .. why can you generate the id as specified in the answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how you generated the id. Can you elaborate? Should the generated ID in the schema/solrconfig be available during delta import? Because for me it isn't.

Comment: with the SQL query you can add select 'e1' || k1 AS id ...... to add id by yourself instead of autogenerating it